# Start kubernetes_job on AWS Secret rotation

Tags: terraform

I have the following AWS Secret rotation being kicked off every 30 days

```
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_rotation" "example" {
  secret_id           = aws_secretsmanager_secret.example.id
  rotation_lambda_arn = aws_lambda_function.example.arn

  rotation_rules {
    automatically_after_days = 30
  }
}
```

I would like to execute this `kubernetes_job` every time the secret is rotated:

```
resource "kubernetes_job" "demo" {
  metadata {
    name = "demo"
  }
  spec {
    template {
      metadata {}
      spec {
        container {
          name    = "pi"
          image   = "alpine"
          command = ["sh", "-c", "sleep 10"]
        }
        restart_policy = "Never"
      }
    }
    backoff_limit = 4
  }
  wait_for_completion = false
}
```

Is this possible to tie these two together?

Comment: I don't think so. But you could maybe try using kubectl for that with a manifest for this job and an external data source: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source.

Comment: @MarkoE This sounds like a good idea. Do you have an example? The example they provided in that link is a bit small :/

Comment: It always is. :) Nope, I don't have an example for that, it was just an idea. Maybe you can start with another example (e.g., only a Pod) and when that is ready move to the one with a Job.